# How to put double and single quote in value of AllowedSymbols variable to use in XSLT Translation

Tags: xslt-1.0

Using XSLT 1.0, in the XLST template below, I want to add the single and double quote to the list of allowed values.  Getting error on vAllowedSymbols2 saying that "string literal not closed".

```
    <xsl:template name="CleanAlphaField">
       <xsl:param name="inputText" />
       <xsl:param name="maxLength" />
       <xsl:variable name="vAllowedSymbols2" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 !@$%()+-_,.;:=[]{}\?&quot;&apos;'"/>
       <xsl:variable name="vAllowedSymbols" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 !@$%()+-_,.;:=[]{}\?'"/>
       <xsl:variable name="truncatedInputText" select="substring($inputText,1,$maxLength)" />
       <!-- return the revised string     -->
       <xsl:value-of select="translate($truncatedInputText,translate($truncatedInputText, $vAllowedSymbols, ''),'')"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: It's working fine with vAllowedSymbols, but not with vAllowedSymbols2.

Comment: Side Note: I decided it's better to do the truncate after stripping the characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to create these as separate variables for XML escaping reasons.

```
<xsl:variable name="singleQuote" select='"&apos;"' />
<xsl:variable name="doubleQuote" select="'&quot;'" />
```

Having done that, you can [concat](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-concat) these together

```
<xsl:variable name="vAllowedSymbols2"
              select="concat($vAllowedSymbols, $singleQuote, $doubleQuote)" />
```

This happens because the XML entity expansion happens before things reach the XSLT processor, so in the minimal case

```
<xsl:variable name="invalid" select="'&apos;'" />
```

the value of @select gets expanded and the XSLT engine sees an attribute (name=`{}select`, value=`'''`) and doesn't know that it came from an entity expansion; it just knows that three single quotes doesn't make a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Wow, I think I tried separate variables, but I didn't reverse the single double quotes around the &apos; like you did.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do simply:

```
<xsl:variable name="vAllowedSymbols2">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 !@$%()+-_,.;:=[]{}\?"'</xsl:variable>
```